# PHPCS cannot be set to PSR2 by default

Tags: phpcs

I'm trying to set up PHPCS to run with PSR2 by default instead of having to specify it on each run.

I set the default with `phpcs --config-set standard PSR2`  When I check the configuration, it appears to be set:

```
$ phpcs --config-show
Using config file: /usr/bin/CodeSniffer.conf

standard: PSR2
```

When I actually run it on files, it runs as PEAR:

```
$ phpcs -v transarray.php 
Registering sniffs in the PEAR standard... DONE (28 sniffs registered)
Creating file list... DONE (1 files in queue)
Changing into directory /root
Processing transarray.php [PHP => 136 tokens in 26 lines]... DONE in 2ms  (11 errors, 0 warnings)
...
```

If I run `phpcs --standard=PSR2 ...` it works correctly, but I would rather not have to include that every single time I run it.

The code errors reported match the standards in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-default-coding-standard) you have to use `default_standard` as configuration key. So the command must be:

`phpcs --config-set default_standard PSR2`

Comment: You've earned your username!  I can't believe the number of people who missed that.  Thanks you so much.  I'm about 10 ways into this and have been looking through source code to figure it out.  I feel dumb, but I can probably contribute some other fixes to PHPCS now that I've been through it so much.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to help.